# Is this a run-on sentence? & What about the phrase "no matter..."

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning, grammaticality-in-context, commas, run-on-sentences

The following sentence comes from a Youtube video regarding idioms:

> "So, he finally decided that letting Annette go would be the lesser of the two evils as an angry staff is a less productive staff **and** one person, **no matter how good**, can eventually be replaced."

The first question, Shouldn't a comma be placed before the dependent clause "and one person, no matter how good, can eventually be replaced."? Also, I think, it could remove a potential ambiguity or confusion.

Secondly, I don't grammatically fully understand the use of the phrase "no matter how good" in that context; I mean, what is the grammatical justification for that kind of use?

Were I to write the sentence, it would look somewhat like this:

> So, he finally decided that letting Annette go would be the lesser of the two evils as an angry staff is a less productive **staff, and** one person, no matter how good **he is**, can eventually be replaced.

Further context:

> "The manager found himself between a rock and a hard place when he had to either lose Annette, his best salesperson, or promote her and anger most of his senior staff, who don’t like her."

Comment: Your guess is right **no matter how good he is** is what it means. I'd also place a comma before **and one person**.

Comment: So much confusion in your mind! You're messing up run on sentences, coordinating and subordinating conjunctions, dependent and independent sentences, punctuation, etc. The example sentence is correct as it is, including punctuation.

Comment: A lot of uses of commas are matters of style and taste, but in this case, I don't see any reason to put a comma before *and*.  The structure of the sentence is basically "He decided X as Y and Z".  It reads less fluently with a comma there.

Answer (score 1):

A run-on sentence occurs whenever you have two clauses that could stand as sentences in their own right, and are joined ***without and appropriate conjunction or punctuation***.

In your example, they are joined with an appropriate conjunction, ***and***. Thus, it is not a run-on sentence.

The use of a comma in addition to the conjunction in such a situation is a largely stylistic matter.

As to the matter of ***no matter***, it is being used *parenthetically*, as an aside that adds supplemental meaning without being grammatically or syntactically (or usually even semantically) essential. It is often used thus, appearing directly after the noun to which it relates. You might understand it better if you substituted it with "no matter good *that person is*", or perhaps *might be*.